# products html to asp page redirection using htaccess method

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all of products from oldsite to corresponding newsite as follows using htaccess.

if input is : oldsite.com/prod1.html
then output should be : newsite.com/products.asp?code=prod1

if input is : oldsite.com/prod2.html
then output should be : newsite.com/products.asp?code=prod2

and same to prod3,prod4 and so on.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've tried until now. Plus I think I saw this same question a few minutes ago with another account... Where we told the person to post examples of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following mod_alias based solution:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/httpdocs/([^.]+)\.html$ http://newsite.com/products.asp?prod=$1
```

this will redirect

```
http://example.com/prod0-9.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/products.asp?code=prod0-9
```

Comment: thanks a lot , just a little help more is required. oldsite address is http://www.example.com/httpdocs/prod0-9.html   i forgot to mention httpdocs folder in question.